# Use FluentAPI's to execute against a HTTPClient instead of a destination name

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We want to use the VDM generated API's to execute against a Http client instead of a destination.

Currently the fluent api's work along  the lines ::

service......execute(new ErpConfigContext(destinationName));

Is it Possible to have it work against a HTTP client.

Use Case :: We are trying to consume Odata Services in non CF environments.. where Destinations are not available.

Comment: Hi Anirban, I updated my answer below with an easier approach on how to use the SDK with "custom" destinations in version 3+ of the SAP Cloud SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Starting with version 3.0.0 of the SAP Cloud SDK you are now able to create your own Destinations, so you are no longer reliant on Destinations provided by the SDK.

This might then look something like this:

```java
HttpDestination httpDest = DefaultHttpDestination.builder("https://sap.com").build();

service.getAllEntities().execute(httpDest);
```

---

There is no direct possibility to do this via the VDM API as of version 2.19.1.

To circumvent this, however, you could override the [`DestinationFacade`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/connectivity/DestinationFacade.html) (cf. [`AbstractDestinationFacade`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/connectivity/AbstractDestinationFacade.html)) in the [`DestinationAccessor`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/connectivity/DestinationAccessor.html).
This would allow you to plug your "non-destination" concept into the VDM.

Comment: We were able to overwrite with our DestinationFacade and make our use case work.

Comment: When we tried to modify the use case and add a https destination with basic auth and proxytype internet , we get nullpointer exception form the metadata. Any suggestion on how to adapt to an https use case.

Comment: This should not be a problem out of the box. Please open a new question, describe your setup and provide the stacktrace. Thanks!